# More than one api key in google-services.json

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, api-key

I have a firebase project with 2 android apps, the `com.app.example` and `com.app.example.dev`. One is points to the production environment and is published in the play store, the other is for development purpose is not published online.

The 2 apps have different api keys, visible in the `GCP -> APIs and services -> Credentials`

According to [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#faq-two-keys-for-same-app-in-config) on Firebase docs:

> All Android apps in the Firebase project are listed in the same config
> file, and **each app can only have one API key** listed. Each app in this
> config file can have a different key listed, though.

That is not the case, because both the Api keys are set in the production and development firebase apps in the provided `google-services.json`.
I resolved the problem removing the wrong Api key from the two apps, but this means that I had to manually `edit google-services.json`.

How can I resolve the problem without touching the file?

Comment: @fikkatra No, I manually edited the downloaded google-services.json. I removed the wrong api key from both apps, keeping the one correct for each one.